# Unable to open display 0 oracle 11g installation ubuntu 32bit

Tags: ubuntu, oracle11g

So I did enough stuff to get lost trying to install Oracle 11gR2 enterprise needed for a JavaApp on my Ubuntu. I have the Oracle user the group and the subgroup assigned to it, but on running the DB installer it checks the colors asigned to the monitor via command `/usr/bin/xdpyinfo` which doesn't seem to be working with that oracle user.

It returns this:

```
No protocol specified
/usr/bin/xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":0".
```

This command perfectly works with any other user.

**What should I do? How do I asign all of the rest system normal commands to user oracle?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the DISPLAY environment variable. Since you say it works with any other user, it sounds like you are perhaps connecting to your server as one user and then su'ing to the Oracle account. If so you can check the normal user's `$DISPLAY` environment variable before su'ing, and then do `export DISPLAY=<that value>` from the Oracle account before running the installer.